# Неожиданное поведение фильтров исключений

Tags: c#, .net, исключения

Искал информацию по фильтрам исключений в C# и наткнулся на [эту статью](https://habrahabr.ru/company/enterra/blog/252437/). В статье описывается случай, когда происходит исключение непосредственно внутри фильтра исключений, например:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        TestExceptionFilters();
    }
    public static void TestExceptionFilters()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("Original Exception");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) when (MyCondition())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
    public static bool MyCondition()
    {
        throw new Exception("Condition Exception");
    }
}
```

Со следующим комментарием к коду:

> Таким образом, мы можем указать условие в фильтре исключений; catch-блок будет исполняться только в том случае, если условие выполнилось. И мы можем использовать bool-функцию в качестве условия. Но что произойдёт, если само условие выбросит исключение? Ожидаемым поведением является следующее: исключение игнорируется, условия считается ложным

Вот уж для меня действительно стало неожиданным, что ожидаемое поведение - это **игнорирование** исключения. Сразу не поверил, но компилятор ведет себя так, как и ожидают люди: игнорирует исключение в фильтре

Сам вопрос: как так произошло, что игнорировать исключения - это норма? А что если я захочу логгировать ошибку в фильтре (это одно из применений фильтров исключений), а у меня там будет ошибка (нет такого файла, например), то мало того, что я не увижу, что у меня есть ошибка, так еще и не зайду в нужный блок `catch`, так как "условие будет считаться ложным"

Comment: А разве условие не может быть методом внутри которого try...catch  и логировать?

Comment: @vitidev, бесспорно может, но вопрос о другом

Comment: На самом деле это достаточно разумное поведение, так как в случае исключения в фильтре не известно, прошла ли проверка, так что самой разумной стратегией будет вернуть ```false```. То, что исключение внутри фильтра игнорируется, так же разумно, так как иначе ломается проверка изначального исключения.

Comment: 1) Как вы себе представляете обработку исключения в фильтре? 2) Фильтры предназначены в первую очередь для простейших проверок in-place и если проверка может выбросить исключение, возможно, вы делаете что-то не так.

Comment: @andreycha это уже неформальные правила архитектуры и стиля кодирования. Но фактически приведенный пример кода валиден для компилятора, а значит имеет право на существование

Comment: @UladzimirPalekh, не совсем разумно игнорировать. Сейчас объясню: я (или не я) писал функцию для фильтра и не обернул ее в try (устал/забыл/захотел ловить в другом месте/вообще не я писал, просто помогаю). Затем происходит ошибка приложение, валиться и я не могу понять в чем именно ошибка! Потому что то исключение проигнорировалось, в нужный catch я не зашел. Поиск ошибки превратился в ад

Comment: @andreycha, 1) не очень понял вопрос. 2) грубо говоря фильтр придуман именно для такого логирования, так как это единственная возможность залогирроваться до "раскрутки стека". Все остальное можно сделать и без фильтра - http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com.by/2014/12/exception-filters-in-c-60.html

Comment: @Qutrix, фильтры придуманы не для логгирования, а для фильтрации, как бы странно это не звучало. То, что их пытаются использовать для других задач, это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: @UladzimirPalekh, почитайте мой ответ Андрею (мой комментарий над Вашим)

Comment: 1) Предположим, исключение из `MyConditon()` не подавляется. Как и где оно должно обрабатываться вне этого метода? И что с оригинальным исключением? Напишите C# псевдокод, как бы вы хотели обрабатывать такое исключение (язык он ведь не только о том, логично что-то или нелогично, но и о том, как это будет выглядеть в тексте). 2) Фильтр придуман -- сюрприз -- именно для фильтрации (то, что у Теплякова идет сценарием под номером два). Все остальное -- побочные эффекты, которые можно использовать как лазейки.

Comment: мощной лампой накаливания можно кипятить воду, но долго, неудобно и колба скорее всего взорвется. Мощным кипятильником можно освещать комнату, но неудобно, мало света и кипятильник скорее всего сгорит, так же и тут.. Использование побочных эффектов в качестве основного функционала ни к чему хорошему никогда не приводит

Comment: @andreycha, 1)хороший вопрос уровня создания языка, и я так быстро ответ не придумаю (не уверен, придумаю ли вообще), но хотя бы как написано в ответе: "Можно было бы пробросить полученное исключение на уровень выше, а в свойстве InnerException передать исходное исключение, из-за которого все и произошло". Даже это мне кажется лучшим, чем искать блуждающую ошибку (пример писал выше в комментарии). 2) для фильтрации можно обойтись старым синтаксисом, чего не сделаешь с логированием, поэтому считаю что это более важный кейс, чем фильтрация. Но в любом случае это не "я что-то делаю не так"

Comment: @rdorn, еще раз повторюсь: без синтаксиса "фильтов исключений" можно сделать фильтрацию, в отличии от логирования до "раскрутки стека", поэтому считаю логирование не побочным эффектом, а чуть ли не основным функционалом. Ну нет в C# другого способа логировать до "раскрутки стека", кроме как фильтр исключений, в отличии от непосредственно фильтрации (ее можно сделать и без фильтра исключений)

Comment: @Qutrix, судя по предложенному синтаксису, разработчики языка считают иначе. То, что есть задача, которая может достаточно удобно решаться при помощи механизма, который предназначается для решения другого класса задач, это хорошо, но всё же при использовании нестандартных механизмов стоит читать документацию и следить за ограничениями. Не думаю, что в коде того же Roslyn в фильтрах есть необрабатываемые исключения.

Comment: @UladzimirPalekh, "То, что есть задача, которая может достаточно удобно решаться при помощи механизма" - логирование до "раскрутки стека" - задача которая решается ТОЛЬКО при помощи механизма фильтра исключений. "следить за ограничениями" - компиляторы для того и придуманы, чтобы не я следил за ограничениями. "Не думаю, что в коде того же Roslyn в фильтрах есть необрабатываемые исключения" - они, несомненно, молодцы, но человеку свойственно ошибаться

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Очень похоже что это не норма, а банальная необходимость. И вот почему:
в .NET и C# в частности **гарантируется** выполнение блока `finally`, независимо от результатов работы кода в блоке `try` и наличия либо отсутствия обработки возникших исключений в блоках `catch`. Ваш код порождает исключение в потоке управления конструкции `try ... catch ... finally`. Если бы оно не было проигнорировано, это привело бы к прерыванию потока управления и невозможности выполнить блок `finally`. Но выполнение `finally` гарантировано спецификацией.

Получили явное противоречие. Простой выход из ситуации - игнорировать исключения в потоке управления конструкции `try ... catch ... finally`, для соблюдения спецификации.

Можно было бы пробросить полученное исключение на уровень выше, а в свойстве `InnerException` передать исходное исключение, из-за которого все и произошло, но от такого решения будет больше путаницы, чем пользы.

PS: упомянутый поток управления не имеет ни какого отношения к многопоточности

---

Непосредственно к вопросу не относится, но для общей картины нужно добавить, что есть ряд исключений, для которых не выполняются ни `catch`, ни `finally`. Как правило это исключения вызывающие падение домена приложения или самой CLR, причина которых может быть как серьезной внутренней ошибкой приложения (например StackOverflowException), так и внешними проблемами CLR или операционной системы (частный случай OutOf MemoryException).

Comment: Предположение интересное, но считаю, что "Можно было бы пробросить полученное исключение на уровень выше..." лучше, так как.. приведу тут комментарий, который я писал к вопросу: "я (или не я) писал функцию, которую буду вызывать из фильтра и не обернул ее в try (устал/забыл/захотел ловить в другом месте/вообще не я писал, просто помогаю). Затем внутри этой функции генерируется исключение, приложение валиться и я не могу понять в чем именно ошибка или, что хуже, неправильно работает! Потому что то исключение проигнорировалось, в нужный catch я не зашел. Поиск ошибки превратился в ад"

Comment: @Qutrix в любом случае, пока есть как есть, можете предложить Microsoft внести соответствующие изменения, вроде бы есть возможность отправлять команде разработки свои пожелания. Возможно при достаточном обосновании эти изменения включат в последующие версии. VS Enterprise, кстати, показывает эти исключения в диагностике, так что для больших проектов проблемы с отладкой быть не должно, хотя и менее удобно.

Comment: может есть объяснение, просто я не могу его найти, поэтому спросил тут ;) а мой английский не настолько хорош, чтоб я четко и понятно (я и на русском-то не очень могу) выразить свои пожелания, к сожалению. В любом случае спасибо всем за участие
З.Ы. "VS Enterprise, кстати, показывает эти исключения в диагностике" - в диагностике это как?

Comment: @Qutrix во время отладки можно включить окно Diagnostic tools, там отображается расход памяти, процессора, события CLR, исключения. Довольно удобная штука

Comment: Совсем **не гарантируется**, так как есть ряд исключений (corrupted state exceptions), при возникновении которых блок `finally` никогда не исполнится. К таким исключениям относятся `StackOverflowException`, `OutOfMemoryException` и некоторые другие.

Comment: @Nikita естественно, потому что когда падает сама CLR или домен приложения, ни чего гарантировать нельзя =) но спасибо что дополнили, сейчас допишу